# What is a good way to convert a valid or invalid JSON to a string?

Tags: java, json, jackson, escaping

I have a service that gets JSON inputs, but occasionally also gets invalid JSON contents. I don't have control over this behavior. The input can be

```
{"key":{"k1":"v1"},"key2":"value2"}
```

or

```
{"key":{"k1":"v1"},"Random String"}
```

My idea is to wrap this whole thing into a valid JSON as below

```
{"id":"some id", "raw_data":"the above input as string"}
```

I know I can escape all quotes and treat it like a string, but is there a cleaner way to convert JSON to escaped string?

FWIW, I'm using `Jackson` for parsing and processing.

EDIT: The JSON schema isn't clear upfront and can vary with different inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can escape all quotes and treat it like a string, but is there a cleaner way to convert JSON to escaped string?

Just create a class with the `raw_data` attribute, set this attribute with the JSON you have received (correct or incorrect) and let Jackson serialise it (and take care of making it a correct JSON).

Comment: The data in `raw_data` isn't using a defined schema. I updated the questions to reflect this.

Comment: @VaishakSuresh I do not understand how it changes anything. Whatever you get from the client - valid or invalid - put it inside "raw_data" as a String. Jackson will do the rest.